# Do Tide Pods laundry detergent have 10 times the cleaning power of other liquid bargain brands?

Tags: clothing, cleaning

Tide makes [a lot of claims about their product](https://tide.com/en-us/shop/type/laundry-pods/tide-pods-laundry-detergent)

> They pack **10X cleaning power*** in an innovative, three chamber design separating key ingredients until they hit the wash for maximum cleaning power. More than just a liquid in a pouch, these reformulated laundry pacs reveal Tide’s brightest clean yet.
>
> [...]
>
> *Stain Removal of 1 dose vs. 10X doses of the leading liquid bargain brand

Is there any evidence Tide Pods are more effective than other liquid detergent brands?

Comment: I am thinking this is going to be a very difficult question to answer. What constitutes better cleaning?  Anyone have a Consumer Reports subscription? https://www.consumerreports.org/products/laundry-detergent/tide-pods-202776/overview/

Comment: "Cleaning power" is an undefined unit of measurement. They say "stain removal of 1 dose", but don't specify what kind of stain. Is there any detail on their exact testing methodology?

Comment: no need to "(sic)" the use of "pac" - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pac